# Migrating existing database to Amazon RDS

Tags: mysql, database-migration, amazon-rds

How can I import existing MySQL database into Amazon RDS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to import data :

1. `mysqldump` : If you data size is less than 1GB, you can directly make use of mysqldump command and import your data to RDS.
2. `mysqlimport` : If your data size is more than 1GB or in any other format, you can compress the data into flat files and upload the data using sqlimport command.

Comment: Follow the best practices here - they hit the common sense points plus due to their InnoDB and binlog heavy organization they tell you how to speed import and avoid IOPS penalties: [link]http://aws.amazon.com/articles/2933

Answer (score 12):

I found [this page on the AWS docs](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/2933) which explains how to use mysqldump and pipe it into an RDS instance.

Here's their example code (use in command line/shell/ssh):
`mysqldump acme | mysql --host=hostname --user=username --password acme`

where `acme` is the database you're migrating over, and `hostname`/`username` are those from your RDS instance.

You can connect to RDS as if it were a regular mysql server, just make sure to add your EC2 IPs to your security groups per [this forum posting](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=81774&tstart=0&messageID=309154#309154).

I had to include the password for the local mysqldump, so my command ended up looking more like this:
`mysqldump --password=local_mysql_pass acme | mysql --host=hostname --user=username --password acme`

FWIW, I just completed moving my databases over. I used [this reference for mysql commands](http://www.ntchosting.com/mysql/create-user.html#How_to_add_a_new_account_in_MySQL_by_using_CREATE_USER) like creating users and granting permissions.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The part about the needing to include the password for the local DB helped me, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm a big fan of the [SqlYog](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php) tool.  It lets you connect to your source and target databases and sync schema and/or data.  I've also used [SQLWave](http://www.nerocode.com/), but switched to SqlYog.  Been so long since I made the switch that I can't remember exactly why I switched.  Anyway, that's my two cents.  I know some will object to my suggestion of Windows GUI tools for MySQL.  I actually like the SqlYog product so much that I run it from Wine (works flawlessly from Wine on Ubuntu for me). 
This [blog](http://www.webyog.com/blog/2009/11/06/amazon-rds-the-beginners-guide/) might be helpful.

[image]

Comment: **Be careful of the pit falls here**. Does this app use your PC as a middleman between the two? Furthermore I believe large transactions incur a 3x IOPS penalty for large DBS (See link). Hence the methods described here: [link]http://aws.amazon.com/articles/2933 are proposed and have been ideal for minimizing excess IOPS and reducing time to roll out.

Answer (score 3):

A quick summary of a GoSquared Engineering post:

### Configuration + Booting

- Select a maintenance window and backup window when the instance will be at lowest load
- Choose Multi-AZ or not (highly recommended for auto-failover and maintenance)
- Boot your RDS instance
- Configure security groups so your apps etc can access the new instance

### Data migration + preparation

1. Enable binlogging if you haven't already
2. Run `mysqldump --single-transaction --master-data=2 -C -q dbname -u username -p > backup.sql` on the old instance to take a dump of the current data
3. Run `mysql -u username -p -h RDS_endpoint DB_name < backup.sql` to import the data into your RDS instance (this may take a while depending on your DB size)
4. In the meantime, your current production instance is still serving queries - this is where the `master-data=2` and binlogging comes in
5. In your backup.sql file, you'll have a line at the top that looks like `CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_LOG_FILE=’mysql-bin.000003′, MASTER_LOG_POS=350789121;`
6. Get the diff since `backup.sql` as an SQL file `mysqlbinlog /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.000003 --start-position=350789121 --base64-output=NEVER > output.sql`
7. Run those queries on your RDS instance to update it `cat output.sql | mysql -h RDS_endpoint -u username -p DB_name`
8. Get the new log position by finding `end_log_pos` at the end of the latest `output.sql` file.
9. Get the diff since the last `output.sql` (like step 6) and repeat steps 7 + 8.

### The actual migration

1. Have all your apps ready to deploy quickly with the new RDS instance
2. Get the latest `end_log_pos` from `output.sql`
3. Run `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;` on the old instance to stop all writes
4. Start deploying your apps with the new RDS instance
5. Run steps 6-8 from above to update the RDS instance with the last queries to the old server

### Conclusion

Using this method, you'll have a small amount of time (depending on how long it takes to deploy your apps + how many writes your MySQL instance serves - probably only a minute or two) with writes being rejected from your old server, but you will have a consistent migration with no read downtime.

A full and detailed post explaining how we (GoSquared) migrated to RDS with minimal downtime (including error debugging) is available here: https://engineering.gosquared.com/migrating-mysql-to-amazon-rds.

Answer (score 2):

I am completely agree with @SanketDangi.

There are two ways of doing this one way is as suggested using either `mysqldump` or `mysqlimport`.

I have seen cases where it creates problem while restoring data on cloud gets corrupt.

However importing applications on cloud has became much easier now a days. You try uploading your DB server on to public cloud through ravello.

You can import your database server itself on Amazon using ravello.

Disclosure: I work for ravello.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest example:

```
# export local db to sql file:
mysqldump -uroot -p —-databases qwe_db > qwe_db.sql

# Now you can edit qwe_db.sql file and change db name at top if you want

# import sql file to AWS RDS:
mysql --host=proddb.cfrnxxxxxxx.eu-central-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port=3306 --user=someuser -p qwe_db < qwe_db.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

AWS RDS Customer data Import guide for Mysql is available here : http://aws.amazon.com/articles/2933

- Create flat files containing the data to be loaded
- Stop any applications accessing the target DB Instance
- Create a DB Snapshot
- Disable Amazon RDS automated backups
- Load the data using mysqlimport
- Enable automated backups again

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the terminal this is what worked for me:

```
mysqldump -u local_username -plocal_password local_db_name | mysql -h myRDS-at-amazon.rds.amazonaws.com -u rds-username -prds_password_xxxxx remote_db_name
```

and then i used MYSQL WorkBench (free download) to check it was working because the command line was static after pressing submit, i could have probably put -v at end to see it's output

Note: there is no space after -p

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps which i have done and had sucess.

## Take the MySQLdump of the needed database.

**mysqldump -u username -p databasename --single-transaction --quick --lock-tables=false >databasename-backup-$(date +%F).sql**

( Dont forget to replace the username as root – most of the times, and databasename -> Db name of database which you are going to migrate to RDS )

## Once prompted, enter your password.

Once done, login to the RDS Instance from your MySQL server ( Make sure the security groups are configured to allow the connection from Ec2 to RDS )

## mysql -h hostaddress -P 3306 -u rdsusername -p

( Dont forget to replace hostaddress with the address of your RDS Instance and rdsusernmae with username for your RDS Instance, when prompted give the password too )

You find that hostaddress under – Connectivity & security -> Endpoint & port under RDS Database From AWS Console.

## Once logged in, create the database using MySQL commands :

**create database databasename;
\q**

## Once Database is created in RDS, Import the SQL file created in Step 1 :

**mysql -h hostaddress -u rdsusername -p databasename < backupfile.sql**

This should import the SQL file to RDS and restore the contents into the new database.

Reference from : https://k9webops.com/blog/migrate-an-existing-database-on-mysql-mariadb-to-an-already-running-rds-instance-on-the-aws/